# C, shares one address but different outputs

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int MAX = 999;
    
    printf("MAX=%d\n", MAX);
    
    int* ptr = (int*)&MAX;
    
    *ptr = 666;
    printf("MAX=%d\n", MAX);
    printf("*ptr=%d\n", *ptr);
    printf("ptr=%p\n", ptr);
    printf("&MAX=%p\n", &MAX);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
none
MAX=999
MAX=999
*ptr=666
ptr=0x7ffee97daa58
&MAX=0x7ffee97daa58
```

Here is my question,
`ptr` and `&MAX` shares one specific memory address(`0x7ffee97daa58`)
but why `MAX` value and `*ptr` do not match?

Comment: That's why you don't point an `int *` to a `const int` and modify its value.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons
You should write an answer

Comment: What's probably happening is that since the compiler knows that `MAX` should not change, it doesn't bother to re-fetch its value from memory each time it is used, but just keeps using the same value `999` throughout.  So you may indeed be modifying the memory allotted to `MAX`, but the code never notices.  Of course, this is only one of many types of undefined behavior that could result from doing this; another is a straight-up crash.

Comment: If you can read assembly language, you can [see](https://godbolt.org/z/vgz2RS) that's exactly what `gcc -O` does with this code.  Note the `mov $999, %esi` before the second call to `printf`; the compiler hardcoded the immediate value instead of fetching it from memory.

Comment: Every time you cast const away from a pointer, God kills a kitten.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing isn't allowed by the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  From section 6.7.3p6 regarding the `const` qualifier:

> **If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
> const-qualified type through use of  an  lvalue  with
> non-const-qualified  type,  the  behavior  is  undefined.**   If  an
> attempt  is made to refer to an object defined with a
> volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with
> non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

`MAX` is a const qualified object, and you're attempting to modify it via a non-const pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as making an apparent modification to `MAX` which doesn't seem to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Const really means "read only".

As you've found out, the value of const objects can change, but you have to use devious methods to do it. And while using these devious methods you invoke Undefined Behaviour.